# Does't work django-admin startproject mfdw_site

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-3.10

I installed Python,and then Django.I checked that Django is installed with `--version` command.I installed VENV.

Now I want to start a Project,but `django-admin startproject my_site` does't work.

I'm working with VScode.

What can I do?

Comment: I intalled Django inside the VENV.I'm working on windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solution is for windows,so

first you have to create your VENV ;

python -m venv my_venv

then you have to activate it in my case windows;

my_venv/Script/activate

and then after you activate the Virtual environment :

pip install django

after that you can run either:

django-admin.exe startproject my_site

or:

django-admin startproject my_site

in some case's it's :

django-admin.py  startproject my_site

i hope it's helped

Comment: I did all you said,all worked except the startproject.I tried many options,but they does't work.

Comment: can you maybe share a Picture with the error so we can read it, or what is the error for example django not found etc,,,,

Comment: I shared the error pic as an answer of my question

Comment: first the error message is saying that django is not in the Environment variable , and you did't activate the Venv Environment, you need to activate the venv Environment , and then run the command django-admin.exe startproject my_site

Comment: Thanks,but I can't activate the venv the way you said,and the ways I searched on the internet

Comment: Can you please tell me other ways you know to activate VENV?

Comment: ok first Create a file for both django project and venv env,

Comment: What will I do the next?

Comment: Thank you very very much for helping me to solve my problems.It worked!!!